# PySimpleGUI: How does one bind elements in a secondary window?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a main window with an element, key = -PATIENT-. When I exit the element a function runs to capitalise the entry and to update the element. All good. I also have a secondary window with an element,key = -NAME-. I want to be able to bind the secondary window element so that when I exit it, it will also run a similar function to capitalise the entry and update the element. This is where I have a problem.
When a name is entered in the -PATIENT- element, on FocusOut the name is capitalised and checked against a list of names. If the names is not in the list a popup asks if it should be put into the secondary window element. If affirmative this is done. However, if from the dropdown menu (Edit) a new name should be added to the -NAME- element of the secondary window, then if the name is in lower case, the function to change its first letters to uppercase should run. I cannot get this binding to work for the secondary window. I am attaching a simple sample program (code) to illustrate the problem. Please help.

```
    #CashBook.py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import sqlite3
import datetime as dt
import time
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import subprocess, sys
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('GreenTan')#LightGrey

menu_def = [['File', ['Open', 'Save', 'Exit'  ]],      
           ['Edit', ['Add a Patient','Add a Supplier']],
           ['Reports',['List of patients', 'List of suppliers','Income.....',['by category','by procedure','by patient'],'Expenses by category.....',['by category','by type','by supplier'],],],
           ['Help', 'About...'],]


layout1=[
[sg.T('Patient name:'),sg.In(size=(15,1),key='-PATIENT-')],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.T('')],
]

tabgrp=[[sg.TabGroup([[sg.Tab('Receipts',layout1,key='-RECEIPTS-'),#,title_color='Green',border_width=10,background_color='White',tooltip='Enter receipts',element_justification='centre'),
]], tab_location='topleft',
                       title_color='Red', tab_background_color='Purple',selected_title_color='Green',
                       selected_background_color='Gray', border_width=5)]] 
layout3=[
[sg.T('Closing balance: '),sg.In(size=10,key='_CLOSBAL_'),sg.Push(),sg.Button('Close',button_color='red')]]

layout=[
[sg.Menu(menu_def, )], 
[sg.Push(),sg.T('FootSmart Cash Book',font=('Verdana',24,'bold'),text_color='turquoise'),sg.Push()],
[sg.Push(),sg.T('Enter transaction details in one of the TABS below',font=('Verdana',18,'bold'),text_color ='turquoise'),sg.Push()],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.T('')],
[sg.T('')],
]

layout += tabgrp + layout3
window =sg.Window('Cash Book', layout, finalize=True)
""" Try the binding here. It does not work"""
#window.find_element['-NAME-'].bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')

def capitalise_new_patient_names():

    name=values(add_patient_window(['-NAME-']))
    newname=name.title()
    msg=''
    print(newname)
    
def add_patient_window():
    """
    Function to create secondary window
    """

    add_patient_layout=[
        
        [sg.Push(),sg.T('Add a patient',text_color='blue',font=40),sg.Push()],
        [sg.T('')],
        [sg.T('Patient name'),sg.Push(),sg.In(newname,size=20, key='-NAME-')],
    ]

    add_patient_window=sg.Window('Add a new patient', add_patient_layout, modal=True,finalize=True)#Secondary window

    while True:                             # Event loop for secondary window

        event,values=add_patient_window.read()  # Read secondary window
        if event in (None,'Quit'):
            break

        elif event==window('-NAME-FOCUS OUT'):
            capitalise_new_patient_names()
    """Try binding here. Also does not work"""
    #window.find_element['-NAME-'].bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')
       
    add_patient_window.close()
   
#'++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
window['-PATIENT-'].bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')

def capitalise_patient_names():
    name=values['-PATIENT-']
    Newname=name.title()
    msg=''
    print(Newname)
    window['-PATIENT-'].update(Newname)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel','Close'):
        break
    elif event=='Add Patient':
        add_patient_window()

    elif event=='Add a Patient':
        newname=""
        add_patient_window()
       
    elif event == '-PATIENT-FOCUS OUT':

        capitalise_patient_names()

        pat_name=values['-PATIENT-']

        if not pat_name in ['Nicky Betts','Frank Aldridge','']:

            print('This is a new patient ' + pat_name)

            reply=sg.PopupOKCancel('Warning!', 'This is a new patient. Add patient?')

            if reply=='OK':

                newname=values['-PATIENT-'].title()
               
                add_patient_window()

            elif reply=='Cancel':

                continue
    
window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find the programming logic from your code because lot of issues, so temporary code here for reference only, maybe removed/deleted latter.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def add_patient_window(name):
    layout=[
        [sg.Push(),
         sg.T('Add a patient', text_color='blue',font=40),
         sg.Push()],
        [sg.T()],
        [sg.T('Patient name'),
         sg.Push(),
         sg.In(name, size=20, key='-NAME-')],
        [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('Cancel')],
    ]
    window = sg.Window('Add a new patient', layout, modal=True, finalize=True)
    # window['-NAME-'].bind('<FocusOut>', 'FOCUS OUT')
    name = None
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'OK':       # if event == '-NAME-FOCUS OUT':
        name = values['-NAME-'].title()
    window.close()
    return name

font18 = ('Verdana', 18, 'bold')
font24 = ('Verdana', 24, 'bold')

menu_def = [
    ['File',
        ['Open', 'Save', 'Exit'  ]],
    ['Edit',
        ['Add a Patient','Add a Supplier']],
    ['Reports',
        ['List of patients',
         'List of suppliers',
         'Income.....',
            ['by category',
             'by procedure',
             'by patient'],
         'Expenses by category.....',
            ['by category',
             'by type',
             'by supplier'],
        ],
    ],
    ['Help', 'About...'],
]

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')

tab1=[[sg.T('Patient name:'), sg.In(size=(15,1), key='-PATIENT-')],]
tabgroup = [[sg.Tab('Receipts', tab1, key='-RECEIPTS-')]]
layout=[
    [sg.Menu(menu_def, )],
    [sg.Push(),
     sg.T('FootSmart Cash Book', font=font24,text_color='turquoise'),
     sg.Push()],
    [sg.Push(),
     sg.T('Enter transaction details in one of the TABS below', font=font18,
        text_color='turquoise'),
     sg.Push()],
    [sg.TabGroup(tabgroup, tab_location='topleft', title_color='Red',
        tab_background_color='Purple',selected_title_color='Green',
        selected_background_color='Gray', border_width=5)],
    [sg.T('Closing balance: '),
     sg.In(size=10, key='_CLOSBAL_'),
     sg.Push(),
     sg.Button('Close', button_color='red')],
]
window =sg.Window('Cash Book', layout, finalize=True)
window['-PATIENT-'].bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')
new_name = None

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Close'):
        break
    elif event=='Add Patient':
        new_name = add_patient_window('')
    elif event=='Add a Patient':
        new_name = add_patient_window('')
    elif event == '-PATIENT-FOCUS OUT':
        name=values['-PATIENT-'].title()
        if name not in ['Nicky Betts','Frank Aldridge','']:
            print('This is a new patient ' + name)
            reply=sg.PopupOKCancel('Warning!', 'This is a new patient. Add patient?')
            if reply=='OK':
                new_name = add_patient_window(name)
            elif reply=='Cancel':
                continue
    if new_name:
        window['-PATIENT-'].update(new_name)
        new_name = None

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't I already reply this issue about three days ago ?

Three issues found here

- Find element by `window[key]` for call function `window.find_element(key)`, not `window.find_element[key]`
- Don't use the same name for a function and a variable, like

```py
def add_patient_window():
    ...
    add_patient_window=sg.Window('Add a new patient', add_patient_layout, modal=True,finalize=True)#Secondary window
```

- Element with key '-NAME-' not defined in `window`, so should be binded in window `add_patient_window`, not in window `window`.

replace

```py
...
window =sg.Window('Cash Book', layout, finalize=True)
window.find_element['-NAME-'].bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')
...
def add_patient_window():
...
    add_patient_window=sg.Window('Add a new patient', add_patient_layout, modal=True,finalize=True)
...
```

by

```py
...
window =sg.Window('Cash Book', layout, finalize=True)
...
def add_patient_window():
...
    patient_window=sg.Window('Add a new patient', add_patient_layout, modal=True,finalize=True)
    patient_window.find_element('-NAME-').bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')
    # or patient_window['-NAME-'].bind('<FocusOut>','FOCUS OUT')
...
```

Comment: Gd mng Jason. Yes you did but I could not understand it or get it to work so I deleted the post and posted a sample to illustrate the problem. Thank you for your solution. I still cannot get it to work. When I press Tab to lose focus nothing happens. I put in a line in the method elif event==window('-NAME-FOCUS OUT'): print('Print this message'). Nothing happens which tells me the binding isn't working? Any suggestions? Could you get the code to run the secondary function?

Comment: In statement `elif event==window('NAME-FOCUS OUT'):`, two errors found: (1) should be `window['-NAME-FOCUS OUT']` if it is an element (2) event should compare with event key, not an element, should be `elif event=='NAME-FOCU OUT':`

Comment: Not sure why you need '<FocusOut>' event in secondary window. There's still lot of issues in your code. I add modified code in another post, it maybe look different, but just for your reference.

Comment: Thank you Jason. This works and although it is a different approach it can be incorporated. The reason why I would have liked to have a FocusOut and other bind events in the secondary window is because their are several elements in the window and I want to test some of them for correctness as soon as I leave them. So it is important to know that I can in fact bind an element in a secondary window. In other words I don't want a number of OK buttons. Is my reasoning right? Thank you for your patience and excellent ideas. Kind regards.